# Value of function $f(x)$ in $2$ variable functional equation

Tags: calculus

> If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (x-y)^2$. Then find value of $f(x)$ is , it is given that $f(1)=2$

Try: $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}|f(y+h)-f(y)|\leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(y+h-y)^2$$

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\bigg|\frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h}\bigg|\leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h =0$$

So $|f'(y)|\leq 0\Rightarrow |f'(y)|=0$

So $f(y)=\mathcal{C}$ with using condition we have $f(x)=2$

My Question is How can i solve without using First derivative.

Could some help me to explain it , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $|f(y+h)-f(y)| \le h^2$ (basically your fist line without the limit). Substituting $y+h$ for $y$ gives $|f(y+2h)-f(y+h)| \le h^2$. Via the triangle inequality this leads to $|f(y+2h)-f(y)| \le 2h^2$. Continue this via mathematical induction and you get $|f(y+nh)-f(y)| \le nh^2$.

If you set $y=1$ and $h=\frac{1}{n}$, you get $|f(2)-f(1)| \le n(\frac{1}{n})^2 =\frac{1}{n}$. Since you can make $n$ arbitrarily large, this proves $f(1)=f(2)=2$.

Comment: But above you mention that it is true for $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=\cdots f(n)=2$. How can i prove for all Real $x$ i e $f(x)=2\forallx\in\mathbb{R}$. Please explain, thanks

Comment: Sorry, for the omission. Take a look at  my last inequality $f(y+nh)-f(y)| \le nh^2$ and try to find a substitution for $h$ that puts $|f(x)-f(y)|$ on the left side. On the right, it should now have a slightly more complicated term, but one that nevertheless tends to zero as n tends to infinity.

Comment: I still did not understand lngix. Please explain me. thanks

Comment: Set $y=1, h=\frac{x-1}n$. Then the last inequality states $|f(x) - f(1)| \le n(\frac{x-1}n)^2 = \frac{(n-1)^2}n$. The enumerator is a constant and the denominator goes to infinity with $n$ (it *is* $n$), so the right hand side can be made smaller than any positive real value, so the difference on the left must be 0.